# How to determine the default paper size in Qt (country dependent)

Tags: qt, printing, internationalization, locale

What is a good way to determine the default paper size in a (Qt based) C++ application?

While QLocale provides information about date formats, measurement systems and more, I can't find any way to retrieve the default paper size from there.

For example, in the US they commonly use "Letter" whereas in Germany we commonly use "DIN A4".

The Qt documentation suggests to use the translation files for this purpose (see [Localize section](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/internationalization.html)). However, to my understanding one should keep the display language (specified by the translation file) independent from the system locale so that people can choose the display language independent from the system locale, if they like to.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you trying to get the default paper size of the user's computer (taking into account any localization that the OS has already done), or some "standard paper size" that the government of each country has adopted for her people? I don't think the latter really exists, except by unofficial convention.

Comment: To say it in the words of the "Developing International Software" book: I am looking for the "commonly used paper type" in a specific country. For example, Microsoft Word chooses "DIN A4" as default in Germany whereas I assume it chooses "Letter" as default in the US. To me this sounds locale specific, just as the date format is, but maybe it is just hard coded in Word (if "Germany" then "DIN A4")?

Comment: Figured something out: on Windows the default paper size can be queried via the GetLocalInfo API with the LCType flag set to LOCALE_IPAPERSIZE. So it looks like the QLocale class is simply missing that property.

Comment: I am not sure this will work: QPrinter().paperSize() returns the default paper size of the default printer. The OS or the printer driver may be queried to get the localized paper size. In US, it returns Letter. Don't know if it returns different paper sizes in other countries.

Comment: I had a look at the Qt source. The Win32 QPrinter::paperSize() implementation gets the paper size from "d->devMode->dmPaperSize" in the end (probably native printer environment info, see MSDN: DevMode). As you say the printer probably retrieves its default from the OS. Sounds good enough to me. Thanks. Btw, QPrinter:paperSize() returns "A4" on my OS (Germany).

Comment: Btw, you might want to add this as an answer so that I can accept (if nobody else comes up with a better approach).